# Firebase Realtime Database Update Function

Tags: java, android, firebase, function, firebase-realtime-database

So I'm working on school project about Hotel Reservation System. The problem is on Update function using Firebase Realtime Database. It just not update the data. This code I got from ChatGPT. It show the toast for update successful but in database, its not changing.

DetailsPage.java

```
private void updateBookingData() {
        // Retrieve the updated data from the EditText fields
        String name = nameUET.getText().toString().trim();
        String phone = phoneUET.getText().toString().trim();
        String email = emailUET.getText().toString().trim();
        String checkIn = checkInUET.getText().toString().trim();
        String checkOut = checkOutUET.getText().toString().trim();

        // Check if any of the fields are empty
        if (TextUtils.isEmpty(name) || TextUtils.isEmpty(phone) || TextUtils.isEmpty(email)
                || TextUtils.isEmpty(checkIn) || TextUtils.isEmpty(checkOut)) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Please fill in all the fields", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return;
        }

        // Inside updateBookingData() method in DetailsPage.java
        if (booking == null || TextUtils.isEmpty(booking.getBookingId())) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Booking data not available", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return;
        }


        // Get the user's UID from Firebase Authentication
        FirebaseUser currentUser = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
        if (currentUser == null) {
            // User is not signed in; you may want to handle this case accordingly
            Toast.makeText(this, "User not signed in", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return;
        }

        String userId = currentUser.getUid();

        // Check if the booking object is null or doesn't have a valid bookingId
        if (booking == null || TextUtils.isEmpty(booking.getBookingId())) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Booking data not available", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return;
        }

        // Create a new Booking object with the updated data
        Booking updatedBooking = new Booking(userId, name, phone, email, checkIn, checkOut);

        // Update the data in Firebase Realtime Database using the bookingId
        DatabaseReference databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("bookings")
                .child("users").child(userId).child(booking.getBookingId());
        databaseReference.setValue(updatedBooking)
                .addOnSuccessListener(aVoid -> {
                    try {
                        Log.wtf("BookingName: ", name);
                    }catch (Exception e) {
                        Toast.makeText(this, "Failed to delete booking data: " + e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                    Toast.makeText(this, "Booking updated successfully", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    Intent intent = new Intent(this, ConfirmPage.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                })
                .addOnFailureListener(e -> {
                    Toast.makeText(this, "Failed to update booking data: " + e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                });
    }
```

I need it to update the data in the Firebase Realtime database

Comment: I'm not sure I understand.
What exactly in this code doesn't work the way you expect?
Tell us what is wrong with shared code. Do you have any errors?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: This code not updating the data in the database. I think its because of the updateBooking object is null. But I have no idea how to fix it

Comment: I recommend locally debugging the code to see what exactly is going wrong. If you set a breakpoint on each line of the code you shared, run the code in a debugger, and then check the value of each variable on each line, which is the **first** line that doesn't do what you expect it to do?

Comment: If you're new to debugging on Android, the Android docs have a great page on [debugging your app](https://developer.android.com/studio/debug) to get you started with, including the section on [working with breakpoints](https://developer.android.com/studio/debug#breakPoints) and [inspecting varialbles](https://developer.android.com/studio/debug#variablesAndWatches).